# Recursive data output

Tags: php

```
$dirs = array(
    'root_dir' => array(
        'sub_dir_1' => array(
            0 => 'file'
        ),
        'sub_dir_2' => array(
            0 => 'file'
        ),
        'sub_dir_3' => array(
            0 => 'file_1',
            1 => 'file_2',
            2 => 'file_3'
        )
    ),
);


$render = function($dirs) use (&$render) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($dirs as $parent => $children) {
        if (is_string($parent) === true) {
            echo "<li>$parent</li>";
            $render($children);
        }  else {
            echo "<li>$children</li>";           
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
};

$render($dirs);
```

**Output**

```
<ul>
    <li>root_dir</li>
    <ul>
        <li>sub_dir_1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>file</li>
        </ul>
        <li>sub_dir_2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>file</li>
        </ul>
        <li>sub_dir_3</li>
        <ul>
            <li>file_1</li>
            <li>file_2</li>
            <li>file_3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**Needed output**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        root_dir
        <ul>
            <li>
                sub_dir_1
                <ul>
                    <li>file</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                sub_dir_2
                <ul>
                    <li>file</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                sub_dir_3
                <ul>
                    <li>file_1</li>
                    <li>file_2</li>
                    <li>file_3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        echo "<li>$parent</li>";
        $render($children);
```

Should be:

```
        echo "<li>".$parent;
        $render($children);
        echo "</li>";
```

Otherwise your children are outside of the parent `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

@Niet spotted the mistake but I would go about this a slightly different way:

```
$render = function($dirs) use (&$render) {    
    foreach ($dirs as $parent => $children) {
        $s .= "<li>" . (is_string($parent) ? $parent . $render($children) : $children) . "</li>";       
    }
    return "<ul>$s</ul>";
};

echo $render($dirs);
```

- `is_string` returns `true` or `false`, so no need for the `===` comparison.
- Rather than `echo`ing all over the place, I opted to build the string all in one go and `echo` it at the end. This allows the output of `$render($children)` to be concatenated within the `foreach` loop
- You had a spare `</li>` in your final `echo` statement - I removed it.

Hope it is of some use to you.